# Renderizar radio buttons com base em arrays

Tags: javascript, array, react

Estou desenvolvendo uma avaliação escolar online. Nela recebo algumas questões e cada questão possui várias opções para seleção.

Preciso mostrar as opções como Radio Buttons, permitindo que o usuário selecione 1 opção por questão.

Meu componente de Radio Button é esse:
[Radio Button](https://gist.github.com/fredarend/1c47df06a262e6b2a956c420e604d2e2)

Opions consistem em diversos arrays com as opções das questões, conforme a imagem abaixo:
[image: Arrays de options]

O que acontece é que não estão aparecendo as opções conforme estão nos arrays, na tela estão aparecendo da seguinte forma.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entendo que é devido o fato não estar fazendo corretamente o laço de repetição para pegar o conteúdo desses arrays, porém, gostaria de saber qual é a forma correta.

A forma que estou fazendo é (código completo encontra-se no [GIST](https://gist.github.com/fredarend/1c47df06a262e6b2a956c420e604d2e2)) :

```
{options.map(option => (
  <label htmlFor={String(option.id)} key={option.id}>
    <input
      ref={ref => inputRefs.current.push(ref as HTMLInputElement)}
      type="radio"
      name={name}
      defaultChecked={defaultValue.includes(option.id)}
      value={option.option}
      {...rest}
    />
    {option.option}
  </label>
))}
```

Código onde chamo o componente radio button e passo as options e name está neste [GIST](https://gist.github.com/fredarend/8c410c4b1e2b56c6dd9fe99814349c07).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que deu a entender com base na imagem, `options` é um array de tamanho 1 contendo um outro array de tamanho 4. Serial algo como:

```
[[{id: 1, ...}, {id: 2, ...}, {id: 3, ...}, {id: 4, ...}]]
```

Então você deveria especificar o primeiro elemento em `options.map()`, assim:

```
{options[0].map(option => (
  <label htmlFor={String(option.id)} key={option.id}>
    <input
      ref={ref => inputRefs.current.push(ref as HTMLInputElement)}
      type="radio"
      name={name}
      defaultChecked={defaultValue.includes(option.id)}
      value={option.option}
      {...rest}
    />
    {option.option}
  </label>
))}
```

Chegou a tentar desta forma? Estou presumindo isso com base na primeira imagem que você mostrou do console.log e que este se refere à `options`.

Comment: Certo!
Eu consegui resolver alguns problemas, agora estou com uma dificuldade com relação às interfaces do typescript. Vou editar a questão.

Comment: Não edite, faça outra pergunta com outro tópico.